# Executing function defined in a package

Tags: plsql

Oracle Package
If there are around 200 functions in a package and i only want to execute only one function at a time(without loading the whole package in RAM), how can i do that?

Is there any way ?

Comment: No I don't think so.  The whole package is loaded into the SGA.  But only one copy, which is shared by all users - though of course each user has their own copy of any data associated with the package.  Why are you concerned?

Comment: To add to what Tony has said, if you want to reduce the amount of memory used when a package is added into the SGA, then you'd need to break the package up into smaller packages. However, if you have a package with 200 functions/procedures in it, I'd be very surprised if only one of those functions was being used at any one time - it's much more likely (assuming your package isn't just a hodge-podge of randomly-collected-together functions and procedures) that other people will be using other procedures and functions from the same package.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. not it any version of Oracle up to (and including) 12c

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 11g the answer is "no".

This is because when you call one function from 1000 functions in a package the entire package loads into SGA (System Global Area). But I don't know about Oracle 12 or 18c.